# Stop play sound when not hovering the picture

Tags: javascript, html, audio, hover, mp3

I want the sound to stop play when you are not active hovering the picture. What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
imgarr[i].onmouseout=function(){
    this.setAttribute('src',this.getAttribute('xsrc'))
            }
        })()
    }
```

It is more clearly showed in my jsfiddle example,
http://jsfiddle.net/3tnGL/

Hope you understand.

Sebastian

Comment: Is one of the classes supposed to be an URL of an image?

Comment: Yes, it is. However, it also refers to a class in the js-file.

Comment: In your `onmouseout` function you only change the `src` value. Shouldn't there be a `stop/pause` command as well?

Comment: Thanks! What should I change the `src` value to? 

     `imgarr[i].onmouseout=function(){
     if (this.setAttribute('src',this.getAttribute('xsrc')) )
                    try{
       html5audio.pause()
      }`
      
This feels wrong.. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine

```
imgarr[i].onmouseout=function(){
    this.setAttribute('src',this.getAttribute('xsrc'))
    html5audio.pause()
}
```

I am using FireFox